# Suppress function display in matlab ezpolar

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using `ezpolar` to draw an arc on a compass plot. It's super easy,

```
ezpolar('1', [TH1, TH2])
```

to plot a circular arc with a radius 1 over the range `[TH1, TH2]`. However the function itself "r=1"  gets displayed on the plot, which I do not want. I can't find and [references to how](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezpolar.html?refresh=true) this can be suppressed with an extra parameter or something.

I realise I could plot the arc other ways, but this is a cool function and super-compact, so I'd like to use it here and in the future.

Anyone know how to suppress the displaying of the function on the plot?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky!

It looks like `ezpolar` is one of those MATLAB plots where a lot of things happen but nothing gets returned to the user. However I found the way using `findobj`.

Fiddling with the plot I realized that it is a `'Text'` object what MATLAB puts in the plot, so we can try to find it with

```
h = findobj(gca,'Type','Text')
```

and then delete the text, for example with:

```
h.String='';
```

Tada!

[image]