# Octave: ezpolar labels and grid

Tags: plot, octave

I have looked at the *ezpolar* function in **octave** and I would like to modify labels and grid, let's say simply remove them.
I found this

[Suppress function display in matlab ezpolar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769083/suppress-function-display-in-matlab-ezpolar)

but this is about the title. It can be removed simply by `title("");`.

What is about the other things, can I remove them too?

Thanks
Karl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
spiralObj = ezpolar(@(t) t);
set(spiralObj, 'linewidth', 10, 'linestyle', ':', 'color', [1,0.5,0]);
polarGrid = get(spiralObj, 'parent');
set(polarGrid, ...
    'gridlinestyle', '--', ...
    'linewidth', 1, ...
    'rtick', [1:10], ...
    'ttick', [0:90:359], ...
    'color', [0.45, 0.65, 0.85]);
```

[image]

**UPDATE** To remove all gridlines, point labels, title etc:

```
spiralObj = ezpolar(@(t) t);
set(spiralObj, 'linewidth', 10, 'linestyle', ':', 'color', [1,0.5,0]);
polarGrid = get(spiralObj, 'parent');
set(polarGrid, ...
    'gridlinestyle', 'none', ...
    'rtick', [10], ...
    'ttick', [0], ...
    'title', '', ...
    'color', [0.45, 0.65, 0.85]);
```

[image]

To independently plot stuff on top on an independent axis (which may well contain "text" commands)

```
ax2 = axes()
x = 0:0.01:12*pi; y = sin(x);
plot(x,y, 'linewidth', 5, 'linestyle', ':', 'color', [0,1,0.5]);
set(ax2, 'color', 'none');
axis off; axis([0,12*pi,-2,2]);
```

[image]

Comment: Having said that, some of the options seem buggy or unimplemented at this point. I can't seem to change the grid color or the font color for instance.

Comment: thanks, but it seems as you said also that some properties cannot be changed as I feared.

Comment: While they cannot be changed, they can be _removed_, allowing you to overlay a new set of `axes()` to do things like, insert a new title, bespoke fonts, colours, manually designed gridlines, etc. Slightly more work but completely possible. I can give an example if you'd like to see something specific.

Comment: Hi, thanks. How to remove and replace all these things,  that is really what I want to know. Can you give an example? That would be great.